# How do I manipulate the Query result?

Tags: sql, oracle, data-manipulation

Let say there are students from different classes who took an exam and the sum of the results are displayed

```
Student Table ( Student_id, Grade, Class)
```

So if I want to query the sum of the grade across classes, I will do as follows

```
SELECT Class, SUM(Grade) 
FROM Student
GROUP BY Class
```

Queried Result:

```
Class : Grade
 A    : 500
 B    : 400
 C    : 300
```

But due to cheating incident in class C, the total grade in Class C should be shown as 0.. How do I do that after the first query statement is applied?

Intended Result:

```
Class : Grade
  A   : 500
  B   : 400
  C   : 0
```

After the first query....

Answer (score 3):

You just use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT Class,
       (CASE WHEN Class = 'C' THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Grade) END)
FROM Student
GROUP BY Class
```

Comment: What about COUNT() ? I tried using COUNT, but it keeps saying that not a group by expression....When I added the case statement to the group by part, it then says group by function is not allowed here....

Comment: You don't need to add a `case` statement in the `group by` clause. If you want to count in a similar fashion then just replace `SUM` with `COUNT` in the query from the answer